# Do pads 6,7,8 have to be connected with pad 12 in this layout?

Tags: eaglecad, surface-mount, layout

[image]

In eagle there is a line that says these have to be connected but the data sheet doesn't mention it.
[image]

Here is the data sheet in case it helps https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/468/RPX_1_0-1903909.pdf

Comment: The data sheet shows a suggested layout. Maybe you should follow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 is electrically connected to 6 7 8 internally. If you look at the recommended pcb layout on page 10, it has a pad but its not even connected to anything. Neither are 6 7 8. Its just for heat sinking.

[image]

Eagle is showing them as connected because they are the same net. It can be ignored, once you take into account the information from the datasheet.

Comment: So, 6 7 and 8 wouldn't be connected to anything? Other than the pad printed on the pcb? That makes sense thank you for clarifying. Would you mind clarifying something else for me? I believe the resistor values under "typical application" don't match with "suggested layout". For example in "typical application" R1 goes from Vin/pin16 to CTRL/pin2, but In "suggested application" R3 goes from Vin/P16 to CTRL/pin2. So the resistor numbers are a bit mixed up right?

Comment: The numbering of the resistors in a layout isn't important. Its annoying they don't match but the important part is the electrical connections. @drc